# Как правильно подключить и синхронизировать поток в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, delphi-10-berlin

Читала статьи про потоки. Есть много примеров, пояснений и так далее... Но вот, на примерах, мне так и не ясно - как правильно подключить и синхронизировать поток.

Поясните и покажите, на данном примере, как правильно подключить поток, как синхронизировать. Чтобы, при работе, форма не зависала и программа работала. Хочу полностью отказаться от использования `Application.ProcessMessages();`

Взяла простой код, с чтением построчно (для того что бы, проще было, уловить смысл):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f, f1: TextFile;
  S: string;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
     AssignFile(f, OpenDialog1.FileName);
     reset(f);
     AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Test.txt');
     rewrite(f1);
  end;

  while not Eof(f) do begin
    ReadLn(f, S);

    if (Pos('Запрос', s) > 0) then writeln(f1, S);
  end;

  CloseFile(f);
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Буду благодарна за любую помощь, подсказку а еще лучше реализацию на примере предоставленного кода - с пояснениями что к чему. Я не хочу просто скопировать код и все. Хочу **реально понять** как это работает - что бы в дальнейшем использовать на новых созданных программах и не задавать больше глупых вопросов о потоках.

Дополнение: После окончания работы, добавить, по желанию, сообщение - Работа завершена.

**Вот мои наработки, что тут делаю не так (Подскажите ?):**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
private
{ Private declarations }
protected
procedure Execute; override;
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
 MyThread: TMyThread;
implementation

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  f, f1: TextFile;
  S: string;
begin
if (Pos('Запрос', s) > 0) then writeln(f1, S);
end;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f, f1: TextFile;
  S: string;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
     AssignFile(f, OpenDialog1.FileName);
     reset(f);
     AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Test.txt');
     rewrite(f1);
  end;

  while not Eof(f) do begin
    ReadLn(f, S);

  //Создаем экземпляр потока:
MyThread:=TMyThread.Create(False);
//Параметр False запускает поток сразу после создания, True - запуск впоследствии , методом Resume
//Указываем параметры потока, например приоритет:
MyThread.Priority:=tpNormal;
//Можно указать что после завершения кода поток завершится автоматически:
MyThread.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  end;

  CloseFile(f);
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
end.
```

Comment: Стоит уточнить в вопросе/примере, какие данные вы хотите получать в процессе работы потока (например прогресс выполнения, и сигнал об окончании работы). Пример это сильно не усложнит, зато вы сразу получите все необходимое.

Comment: @Kromster, Благодарна за подсказку, дополнила вопрос. На самом деле хочу разобраться в подключении потоков, потому и создала тему с просьбой показать на примере.

Comment: Еще одно важное уточнение, напомните плиз, у вас Delphi XE какой версии? Т.к. в новых версиях создание потоков существенно упростилось с введением анонимных функций

Comment: @Kromster, У меня сейчас установлена версия: Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Update2.

Comment: @zed, Посмотрите, добавила в вопрос свою попытку - сделать поток. Но не работает где допущены ошибки ?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Посмотрите, добавила в вопрос свою попытку - сделать поток. Но не работает где допущены ошибки ?

Comment: @Igor,  Посмотрите, добавила в вопрос свою попытку - сделать поток. Но не работает где допущены ошибки ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос все еще актуален, Татьяна, то могу предложить следующее решение.

Описываем "тело" потока, добавив в него параметры для путей к файлам - поток сам их откроет в процессе своего выполнения, а также процедуру `DoTerminate`, о которой будет сказано позже. Код приведен ниже.
type

```
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FFileToRead: String;
    FFileToWrite: String;

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure DoTerminate(Sender: TObject);

  public
    // Свойства для открытия файлов (пути к ним)
    property FileToRead : String read FFileToRead write FFileToRead;
    property FileToWrite: String read FFileToWrite write FFileToWrite;
  end;
```

Собственно, работа потока будет заключаться в выполнении процедуры `Execute`. Процедура является виртуальной, что позволяет нам ее *перекрыть* - т.е. объявить в классе с директивой `override`. Это даст компилятору понять, что первой (процедура `Execute` имеется в классе `TThread` по умолчанию) будет вызвана процедура `Execute`, описанная в *нашем собственном* классе. Код процедуры приведен ниже.

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  ReadFrom: TextFile;
  WriteTo: TextFile;
  S: String;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      AssignFile(ReadFrom, FFileToRead);
      Reset(ReadFrom);

      AssignFile(WriteTo, FFileToWrite);
      Rewrite(WriteTo);

      while not EoF(ReadFrom) do
        begin
          ReadLn(ReadFrom, S);
          if Pos('Запрос', S) > 0 then
            WriteLn(WriteTo, S);
        end;

      CloseFile(ReadFrom);
      CloseFile(WriteTo);

      // Помечаем поток как требующий закрытия
      Terminate;
    end;
end;
```

Чтобы получить оповещение об окончании работы потока, можно прибегнуть к использованию свойства `OnTerminate` потока. Для этого следует объявить и описать процедуру, которая будет вызываться потоком по окончанию своей деятельности. Код приведен ниже.

```
procedure TMyThread.DoTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Готово!');
end;
```

Собственно, вызов потока: его создание, выставление некоторых параметров, получение путей к файлам. Код приведен ниже.

```
procedure TForm1.aButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyThread: TMyThread;
  Opened: Boolean;
begin
  // Создаем экземпляр потока
  MyThread := TMyThread.Create(true);
  MyThread.Priority := tpNormal;
  MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  MyThread.OnTerminate := DoTerminate;

  Opened := false;

  // Получаем имена файлов
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      MyThread.FileToRead := OpenDialog1.FileName;
      MyThread.FileToWrite := ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\Test.txt');
      Opened := true;
    end;

  // Проверяем, был ли выбран файл в диалоге выбора
  if not Opened then
    begin
      // Файл не был выбран, значит, уничтожаем созданный поток
      if Assigned(MyThread) then
        MyThread.Free;
      Exit;
    end;

  // Запускаем поток
  MyThread.Start;
end;
```

Как видно, освобождать поток нет необходимости - класс будет самоликвидирован благодаря свойству `FreeOnTerminate`. Проще говоря - запустил и забыл.

*Код протестирован на нескольких текстовых файлах малого размера.*

Полезная информация:

1. [О потоках в целом](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread)
2. [Свойство OnTerminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate)
3. [Процедура Execute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.Execute)

Comment: Дмитрий, конечно вопрос - актуальный, я за сегодня полностью с Вашим кодом разберусь и потом обязательно отпишу.  Спасибо Вам за то что - Помогли: в решении, этого, наболевшего, вопроса!